# PHP output timestamp correctly

Tags: php

I am currently outputting a timestamp from my database (code below) but it's in the wrong format.

```
<p>{$row->last_updated}</p>
```

It is currently outputting `2018-10-23 13:36:40`

The time is ok but the date isn't. This is what I want:

```
23-10-2018 13:36:40
```

What do I need to do with this code in order to display it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date()`

```
<p><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($row->last_updated));?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change date format using PHP date function like this :

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->last_updated))
```